# Exporting ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to a potential employer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, export

I made a pretty cool ASP.NET MVC 3 application, and I want to send it as an attachment to a web firm. I tried playing around in visual web developer but could not get anything :( Should I just zip the project folder up and send it that way? Is there somewhere I can host it for free (doubtful). ANy suggestions on this? Thanks for any replies...

Comment: What do you want them to see - a working site, or your code?

Comment: Can you say/confirm if you want you're client/web firm to run your website? You can just zip it then, you need to host it on their computer or put it online.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix). It's free and it'll install IIS Express which will let your web firm run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can host it for free on your home pc and connection.

Set up IIS on your local machine and host the project, forward port 80 on your router to your pc and use a service like dyndns to get a friendly external address.

Its not as nice a solution as your own pay for external hosting and you shouldn't leave the port forwarding in place for a long time as its a potential security risk.  That said it demonstrates a few extra skills that most employers would be happy to have.

Failing that or if you want to show them your code as well you can either zip the project or publish to a directory and zip that.  Bear in mind that if its over 10 MB a lot of email servers will reject it so you might want to upload to a separate file host like megaupload.